# Are contract public fields readonly?

Tags: solidity, web3js

Looking at the code of [OpenZeppelin's Ownable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol), I see this public field:

```
contract Ownable {
  address public owner;
  :
}
```

Can `owner` be changed from web3 or other contracts? I would guess no, since it would be a security hole.

Does it means that public fields can be accessed only by the contract itself? (something like a public getter and an internal setter)

Can I define something like:

```
contract MyContract {
  Person[3] public persons;
  :
  struct Person {...}
}
```

And be sure that the array can be read and cannot be written by any client?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, marking a variable `public` is equivalent to creating a getter with the same name. There is no built-in support for setters, because you nearly always need some kind of custom code to manage who or how the variable should be set.